# i want show notification at 8:00 am everyday

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I'm trying to send a notification to a user at a specific time at (8:00 am everyday) using an Alarm Manager.
but my code not correct work please help me for show notification

my MainActivity

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AlarmController al=new AlarmController(this);
    al.StartAlarm();

}
```

My AlarmController

```
  public class AlarmController {

    private Context m_Context;
    private AlarmManager mgr;
    private static final long PERIOD = 1000 * 30;

    public AlarmController(Context context){

        m_Context = context;
        mgr = (AlarmManager)m_Context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    }

    public void StartAlarm(){



        Intent i = new Intent(m_Context, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,8);

        PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(m_Context, 0,i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);



        Log.i("AlarmController", "StartAlarm");
    }

    public void StopAlarm(){
        Intent i = new Intent(m_Context, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(m_Context, 0,i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mgr.cancel(pi);

        Log.i("AlarmController", "StopAlarm");
    }
}
```

and OnAlarmReceiver

```
public class OnAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
context.startService(new Intent(context, AppService.class));
```

}
}

```
AppService

 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "start job");

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("My notification")
                    .setContentText("از اپ سرویس!");

    int mNotificationId = 001;
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
    Log.i(TAG, "stop job");
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: You need to set the more specific tome to your calendar instance. When you get a calendar instance then by default it has current time. Here you are modifying the hours of day only. You need to set the minutes also. Set a future time and ensure if alarm fires.

Comment: @SanjeetAjnabee thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmIntent = new Intent(context of current file, AlarmReceiver1.class);

    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Menu.this, 0, alarmIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmIntent.setData((Uri.parse("custom://"+System.currentTimeMillis())));
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

    Calendar alarmStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    if (now.after(alarmStartTime)) {
        Log.d("Hey","Added a day");
        alarmStartTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

     alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
     Log.d("Alarm","Alarms set for everyday 8 am.");
```

Coming to the broadcast receiver class. You need to register your broadcast receiver in the manifest. This will cause you to receive clock events.
    Override the onReceive method of this broadcast receiver and make a notification there itself or make a seperate notification building service and build and display your notification there.

The manifest code snippet:

```
<receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver1"  android:enabled="true">
```

The broadcast receiver code snippet:

```
public class AlarmReceiver1 extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Intent service1 = new Intent(context, NotificationService1.class);
  service1.setData((Uri.parse("custom://"+System.currentTimeMillis())));
              context.startService(service1);
}
```

Notification building service code snippet:

```
public class NotificationService1 extends IntentService{

    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    Notification notification;
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
ontext context = this.getApplicationContext();
           notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Activity to be opened after clicking on the notif);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("test", "test");
            mIntent.putExtras(bundle);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);    

            Resources res = this.getResources();
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                        .setTicker("ticker value")
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setPriority(8)
                        .setSound(soundUri)
                        .setContentTitle("Notif title")
                        .setContentText("Text").build();
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            notification.ledARGB = 0xFFFFA500;
            notification.ledOnMS = 800;
            notification.ledOffMS = 1000;
            notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
            Log.i("notif","Notifications sent.");

    }

}
```

Comment: @EhSAn Thank you sir :) you can upvote and accept the answer so that other people found this helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this set of code your service never going to stop it's works for me. "mgr.setInexactReapeating" not working in many of the lollipop and marshmallows device once it started then lose control over the service this will help you out.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        piLR = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentLR,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        amLR.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                interval, piLR);
    } else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19
            && android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
        piLR = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentLR,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        amLR.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, piLR);
    } else {
        amLR.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, piLR);
    }
```

Comment: no replace the method which you are using

mgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
with above conditions.something like this: 
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){       mgr.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                interval, piLR);
    }
make sure use all the three conditions you have to use

Comment: i replaced .but my app not correct work and repeating every minute show notification