# Alarm title is not updating in notification when it runs on 5.0 but it is updating and runs on 4.1

Tags: android

```
public void al(){
    Calendar myAlarmDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    myAlarmDate.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    myAlarmDate.set(var_Not_Year, var_Not_Month, var_Not_Day,var_Not_Hour, var_Not_Min, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmMgr0 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent0 = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent0.putExtra("Heading",var_Reminder_Title);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent0 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent0, 0);
    alarmMgr0.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, myAlarmDate.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent0);

}
```

This is alarm receiver where the notification title is setup by intent when I get notification of alarm it gets old reminder title if run the application on version 4.1 but when I run this app on version 5.0 it shows old (First time input) reminder title in notification not new reminder set title.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(intent.getStringExtra("Heading"))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, FrontScreen.class), 0))
            .build();

    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

Comment: Try this answer it works for me. [Answer is here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35121191/i-want-show-notification-at-800-am-everyday/35124436#35124436)