# Alarm manager not pushing data in server periodically for nougat

Tags: android

i am using AlarmManager to call the PendingIntent. which triggers the WakefulBroadcastReceiver to push the data in server periodically. but for nougat, its not pushing in the periodic time. and also draining battery too much.

```
my code is here->

public static void startSyncAlarm(String enteredTime) {
    // Construct an intent that will execute the AlarmReceiver
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SyncDbToServerAlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.ENTERED_TIME, enteredTime);
    // Create a PendingIntent to be triggered when the alarm goes off
    final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, SyncDbToServerAlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // alarm needs to be set after 5 minutes of entered time
    // convert entered time to milliseconds
    // create Date object using string time format with using Simple date format
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
    try {
        Date enteredDate = format.parse(enteredTime);
        long enteredTimeInMillis = enteredDate.getTime();
        long intervalMillis = 30 * 60 * 1000; // 30 minutes gap
        long triggerAtMillis = enteredTimeInMillis + intervalMillis;
        Log.d(TAG, "start alarm, enteredTimeMillis = " + enteredTimeInMillis + "\ntriggerAtMillis = " + triggerAtMillis);
    //long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); // alarm is set right away
        syncDbAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        // Setup periodic alarm every 5 minutes
        syncDbAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtMillis/*firstMillis*/,
                intervalMillis, pIntent);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35121191/i-want-show-notification-at-800-am-everyday/35124436#35124436
OR
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35121191/i-want-show-notification-at-800-am-everyday/35127736#35127736

Comment: Suddenly in Nougat the problem is with sending Extras in the Intent. The information does not send.