# Android app which reminds user in every morning

Tags: android, alarmmanager, intentservice, keep-alive

I'm trying to do App which remind user everymorning with push notification.

I have been using AlarmManager, BroadcastReceiver and IntentService.

In code below, I test my AlarmManager with 60 seconds interval.

**Problem**: 
Everything works fine until I shut down my app, alarms not firing anymore.

Any ideas where to go next?

Manifest:

```
<service
    android:name=".IntentMentor"
    android:exported="false" >
</service>

<receiver android:name=".AlertReceiver"
    android:process=":remote">
</receiver>
```

MainActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlertReceiver.class);

final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
// 1s is only for testing
alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis, 1000*60, pIntent);
```

Receiver:

```
public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "MyReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "MyReceiver on receive");
        Intent i = new Intent(context, IntentMentor.class);
        context.startService(i);
    }
}
```

IntentService:

```
public class IntentMentor extends IntentService {

    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    int notifID = 33;

    private static final String TAG = "MonitorService";

    public IntentMentor() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Service method was fired.");
        pushNotification();
    }

    public void pushNotification(){
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notificBuilder.setContentTitle("test");
        notificBuilder.setContentText("this is text");
        notificBuilder.setTicker("this is Ticker?");
        notificBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_info_black_24dp);
        notificBuilder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Card.class);

        TaskStackBuilder tStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        tStackBuilder.addParentStack(Card.class);
        tStackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = tStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        notificBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService((Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE));
        notificationManager.notify(notifID, notificBuilder.build() );
    }
}
```

Comment: [Try this may be this help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35121191/i-want-show-notification-at-800-am-everyday/35127736#35127736)

Comment: I was trying solution behind your link.  Thanks.. but I still have same problem. When app is not open, alarms will not fire.

Comment: Make sure you give the permission for WAKE_LOCK

Comment: [Try this set of code with your.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35121191/i-want-show-notification-at-800-am-everyday/35124436#35124436)
You can change this line "alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis, 1000*60, pIntent);"

Comment: Sorry to be a such a noob.. But what I should use in "intentLR". I don't get meaning of that.

"piLR = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentLR,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);"

Comment: Sorry. Of course. Thanks for patience. Too much dissapointments with my coding today :)

Comment: Ok. With that code "Andy Developer" linked.

With my current emulator  "IF ELSE" goes to:
amLR.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, interval, pIntent);

And this way notification fires only one time. At least interval is something else than 60 seconds. So far only one notification has been fired.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I update your Main Activity code. Now try this.It works fine for me.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlertReceiver.class);

final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
{
   alarm.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            firstMillis, 1000*60, pIntent);
}
else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19
        && android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23)
{
    alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            firstMillis, 1000*60, pIntent);
}
else
{
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            firstMillis, 1000*60, pIntent);
}
```

Comment: For some reason alarm.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, firstMillis, 1000*60, pIntent);  won't work on me. 

setAndAllowWhileIdle takes only 3 params? I'm I just so lost...

Comment: I use: 

alarm.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, interval, pIntent);

And it fires notification only one time.

Comment: You can remove the firstmillis for setAndAllow something like this:
alarm.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,1000*60, pIntent);

Comment: @Wiltson try [this one](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/Wakeful)

Comment: Yes, I realised that. I can't figure out how this setAndAllow... function works.

When I start my app, first notification fires right away. Is it wrong? Is it should fire after 60 seconds?

Another problem is that alarm is not repeating. Only one notification fires.

Comment: Ok. Thanks Andy. I try that link next.

Comment: Sorry to say. That solution behind link 
https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/Wakeful

doesn't work correctly. It fires pushnotification repeatly. But it is not working if app is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Finally. After ten of hours testing, failing, testing, failing.. I wound answer.

[Protected Apps in Huawei Phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638986/protected-apps-setting-on-huawei-phones-and-how-to-handle-it)

So as you see, problem was with my Huawei P8 phone. App needs to be in protected apps list. Now, at lest couple of solutions I tested works fine.

Thanks for everybody to help. I think Andy and others solutions works fine. But Huawei phones have this special issue.