# Android How to show notification twice a day?

Tags: android, time, notifications, alarmmanager

I created a button which shows notification on clicking. but i want notification to show automatically twice a day, at 1:45 pm and 7:00 pm . how to do it?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
private static final int uniqueID = 45612 ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notification.setAutoCancel(true);


}

public void showMe(View view)
{
    //build the notification
    notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.bb);
    notification.setColor(Color.rgb(85,85,85));
    notification.setTicker("Time to nap");
    notification.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.setContentTitle("NapApp");
    notification.setContentText("Going gets tough? take a nap");

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);  //gives access to intent to our app
    notification.setContentIntent(pIntent);

    //builds notification and issues it
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(uniqueID,notification.build());
}
```

}

Comment: For your reference you can [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35121191/i-want-show-notification-at-800-am-everyday/35124436#35124436) and also [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35121191/i-want-show-notification-at-800-am-everyday/35127736#35127736). The link given for only one alarm but you can set multiple alarms.You need to little bit change in code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use AlarmManager to do this.
Follow this documentation provides by Android.
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Answer (score 0):

Schedule multiple notificaiton in a day, use given method it will fire on `1.45 PM` & `7.00 PM`

```
public void scheduleNotification() {

        Calendar mfiringCal  = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar mcurrentCal = Calendar.getInstance();

        mfiringCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
        mfiringCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
        mfiringCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        long intendedTime = mfiringCal.getTimeInMillis();
        long currentTime  = mcurrentCal.getTimeInMillis();

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        if(intendedTime >= currentTime) {

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
            notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");

            PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, mfiringCal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, broadcast);
        }else{

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
            notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");

            PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            mfiringCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            intendedTime = mfiringCal.getTimeInMillis();

            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, intendedTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, broadcast);
        }






        /*-------------- 2nd Notification ------------- */
        Calendar nFiringCal  = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar nCurrentCal = Calendar.getInstance();

        nFiringCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
        nFiringCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        nFiringCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        long intendedTime1 = nFiringCal.getTimeInMillis();
        long currentTime1  = nCurrentCal.getTimeInMillis();

        if(intendedTime1 >= currentTime1) {

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
            notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");

            PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 101, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nFiringCal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, broadcast);
        }else{

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
            notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");

            PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 101, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            nFiringCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            intendedTime = nFiringCal.getTimeInMillis();

            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, intendedTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, broadcast);
        }
    }
```

Comment: where to cALL  this method

Comment: In your first activity, if `MainActivity` is your first activity then call in `onCreate` method on `MainActivity`

Comment: Might be notification can dealy 20-30 seconds

Comment: did i need to set notification title and images in this method

Comment: @AbhishecKumar You have to set alarmreceiver class and then you will get it