# notification when user don't use app 24 hours

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, android-broadcastreceiver

Hellow.
I develop app in which need show local notification when user don't use app 24 hours.

My code:

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReminderReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), getInterval(), pendingIntent);
}

 private int getInterval() {
    int hours = 24;
    int minutes = 60;
    int seconds = 60;
    int milliseconds = 1000;
    return hours * minutes * seconds * milliseconds;
}
```

**ReminderReceiver**

```
 public class ReminderReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent service1 = new Intent(context, ReminderService.class);
    context.startService(service1);
}
}
```

**ReminderService**

```
public class ReminderService extends Service {
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private NotificationManager notificationManager;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
{
    return null;
}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
{
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentTitle("Get Your PSN Code for FREE Now!");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}
}
```

But it does not work as it should, the notification is shown right away when I close the application.  I understand that this is due to the fact that I give the initial time `calendar.getTimeInMillis()`, but I do not know how else.

How to do it right?

Thanks.

Comment: Try [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35127736/5860777) may be this help you. You need to change the time from this code.I hope this will help you.

Comment: @Andy Developer I do not understand how to change this. Perhaps I need to set the current time in the calendar, for example, minus 1 minute, so that the warning does not appear immediately. But I do not know how to set the date minus 1 minute.

Comment: You can [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/625624/5860777) to convert you currentmillis to Hours,Minutes and seconds. When you got that just pass this to Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,Calendar.MINUTE and Calendar.SECOND.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It helped me**

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```