# Android Alarm Scheduling Efficient

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to scheduler alarms which should trigger daily on given time. They should be 100% consistent. Currently I am using

```
 AlamManager.setInexactRepeating
```

and it works a day but not next day and itself starts another day , i mean its not consistent.

So what should I use in Android AlarmManager which trigger must trigger daily and should be efficient ?

Comment: Here's one of my apps, it allows the user to choose to be notified of some "special times" like palindrome hours (10:01) and this kind of weird things. I've used AlarmManager, check it out: https://github.com/magicleon94/SpasmoTime/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/tomorrow/magicleon/spasmotime
In `updateAlarmService`there's a `addAlarmFor` that registers daily repeating alarms for the specified times

Comment: OK i will check it

Comment: note that the code is very similar to the answer posted below

Comment: You can [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35127736/5860777) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35121191/i-want-show-notification-at-800-am-everyday/35124436#35124436)

Answer (score 1):

This code will run the Intent each day on 1 PM or 2 PM. Hope that helps you.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13); // For 1 PM or 2 PM
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,
        new Intent(context, MyClass.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```